# unconditional prior distribution of g-prior (Bayesian Linear Regression)

Tags: bayesian, linear-model

Consider a Gaussian regression model $\boldsymbol{Y} =\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon},\quad  \boldsymbol{\epsilon}\sim N( \boldsymbol{0},\sigma^2I)$

I put a Hyper-g Priors (Liang et al. 2008):

$\boldsymbol{\beta}|\sigma^2,g\sim N(\boldsymbol{0},\sigma^2g(\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X})^{-1})$

$\pi(\sigma^2)\propto \dfrac{1}{\sigma^2}$

$\pi(g) = \dfrac{a-2}{2}(1+g)^{-a/2},g>0$

I am interested in the unconditional prior distribution of $\boldsymbol{\beta}$. I would be grateful if someone could show me how to derive this distribution or suggest some readings on this.